Issues running LinearRegression() from scikit-learn on multiple cores
I want to run LinearRegression() from sklearn library on 5 cores. As the documentation says that the n_jobs  parameter does not cause multiprocessing unless n_targets > 1, I created random data with two y values and attempted to run the program. However, graphs of cpu cores show that only 1 core has been used upwards of 50%. Is the graph normal or is there an issue with the code?
The code I tried:
import os
# Set environment variables to limit the number of threads
for env_var in ["OMP_NUM_THREADS", "OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS", "MKL_NUM_THREADS", "VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS", "NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS"]:
    os.environ[env_var] = "5"

# Importing the necessary libraries
import time
import psutil
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model
from multiprocessing import Process
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from joblib import parallel_backend, Parallel, delayed
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score

# Function to plot CPU usage for all cores
def plot_cpu_usage(usage_data):
    plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))  # Adjust the size as needed
    # print(usage_data)
    for core, usage in enumerate(usage_data):
        ax = plt.subplot(4, 4, core + 1)  # 4x4 grid for 16 cores
        
        # Determine the color based on the maximum usage for the core
        max_usage = max(usage)
        if max_usage > 90:
            line_color = 'red'
        elif max_usage > 75:
            line_color = 'orange'
        elif max_usage < 50:
            line_color = 'blue'
        else:
            line_color = 'purple'
        
        # Plot the usage with the determined color
        ax.plot(usage, color=line_color)

        ax.set_title(f'Core {core}')
        ax.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
        ax.set_ylabel('Usage (%)')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig('cpu_cores_usage [test#4].png')
    plt.show()  # This will display the graph in a window

# Function to monitor CPU usage
def monitor_cpu_usage(duration, interval):
    # Record the start time
    start_time = time.time()
    # Initialize usage data
    usage_data = [[] for _ in range(psutil.cpu_count())]
    
    while (time.time() - start_time) < duration:
        # Get per-core CPU usage
        cores_usage = psutil.cpu_percent(percpu=True)
        # Append usage data for each core
        for i, usage in enumerate(cores_usage):
            usage_data[i].append(usage)
        # Wait for the specified interval
        time.sleep(interval)
    
    # Call the plot function
    plot_cpu_usage(usage_data)

# Function to create a dataset using a seed and random generation
def create_data(seed, sample, all_f, real_f):
    # Seed set as 42 for reproducible results
    np.random.seed(seed)

    # Set the no. of samples and features and create a sxf matrix
    n_samples, n_features = sample, all_f
    X = np.random.randn(n_samples, n_features)

    # Let only the first real_f features actually affect value.
    # We create Y1 as the sum of first 15 features and random noise
    real_p = real_f
    Y1 = np.sum(X[:, :real_p], axis=1) + np.random.normal(size=(n_samples,))

    # Create Y2 similar to Y1
    Y2 = np.sum(X[:, :real_p], axis=1) + np.random.normal(size=(n_samples,))

    # Combine Y1 and Y2 into a single matrix Y
    Y = np.column_stack((Y1, Y2))

    print(X[0:5])
    print(Y[0:5])

    return X, Y

# Function to run your lr.py program
def run_lr_program():
    X, Y = create_data(42, 10000, 5000, 2500)
    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33)

    # Fit the model in parallel
    with parallel_backend('loky', n_jobs=5):
        reg = linear_model.LinearRegression(n_jobs=5)
        reg.fit(X_train, Y_train)

    # Make predictions using the testing set
    Y_pred = reg.predict(X_test)

    # The coefficients
    print("Coefficients: \n", reg.coef_)

    # The intercepts
    print("Intercepts: \n", reg.intercept_)

    # The mean squared error
    print("Mean squared error: %.2f" % mean_squared_error(Y_test, Y_pred))

    # The coefficient of determination: 1 is perfect prediction
    print("Coefficient of determination: %.2f" % r2_score(Y_test, Y_pred))

try:
    # Run the lr.py program in a separate process
    lr_process = Process(target=run_lr_program)
    lr_process.start()

    # Monitor CPU usage while lr.py is running
    monitor_cpu_usage(duration=60, interval=1)  # Monitor for 60 seconds with 1-second intervals

    # Wait for the lr.py program to finish
    lr_process.join()
finally:
    # Ensure proper cleanup
    lr_process.terminate()

The graph I got:

Expected Result:
Graphs of 5 cores showing higher activity than the rest. (I am a beginner and was tasked with learning to utilize specified number of cores only to train my model before I run anything on the server)

You have created so little data it is finishing before the cores really spin up .

I have increased observations and features and have edited my question to reflect the same. From the 20th second mark to 40th second mark, only 5 cores show maximum utilization so is that how it should work? In that case, what are the initial spikes in Core utilization? Thank You in advance.


As the documentation says that the n_jobs  parameter does not cause multiprocessing unless n_targets > 1, I created random data with two y values and attempted to run the program. However, graphs of cpu cores show that only 1 core has been used upwards of 50%. Is the graph normal or is there an issue with the code?

No, this won't attempt process-level parallelism.
The documentation here is a little confusing:

The number of jobs to use for the computation. This will only provide
speedup in case of sufficiently large problems, that is if firstly
n_targets > 1 and secondly X is sparse or if positive is set to
True. None means 1 unless in a joblib.parallel_backend
context. -1 means using all processors. [...]

What this is saying, in psuedocode, is this:
if (n_targets > 1) and (issparse(X) or positive == True):
    use parallelism
else:
    ignore n_jobs

(If you want to check this yourself, you can read the source code.)
Since X is not sparse, and you didn't pass positive, no process-level parallelism is attempted. Even if this were attempting process-level parallelism, the level of parallelism is limited to the number of targets. Since you have 2 targets, it can create at most 2 processes to do this work.
It does some amount of parallelism anyway, which is probably the result of BLAS-level parallelism. NumPy can parallelize some operations, depending on what BLAS implementation you have.
Note that the maximum parallelism when combining process-level parallelism and BLAS parallelism is potentially much higher than 5. If you have 5 processes, and each has 5 threads, then you potentially have 25 concurrent threads running.
